# Delegate is null for some reason

Tags: ios, swift

*I have been debugging for a day and decided I have no idea what is causing the error in my app. It would be awesome if anyone could help me out figure it out*.

So I created a custom `UIView` from a `Nib` File with class name `ManualScreen`. **`xibsetup()`** basically is in `UIView` extension which just loads from the `Nib` file. I want to send the button tap from my view to `ViewController`. I directly did not add this view to the `ViewController` because I need to remove this `ManualScreen` view and add another view in its place when `Segment Control` is moved to another option.

```
class ManualScreen: UIView {
    var mManualViewListener:ManualViewListener!
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        xibSetup()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!{
        didSet {
            print("labelView: \(String(describing: counterLabel))")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if(mManualViewListener != nil){        ->>>this is always nil for some reason
            print("insdie the listener counting")
            mManualViewListener.addCount()
        }else{
            print("listener is nil")
        }
    }
    func addListener(manualViewListener:ManualViewListener){
        print("adding listener")
        mManualViewListener = manualViewListener

    }
}
```

This `UIView` is initilized in the `Viewcontroller` and this `Viewcontroller` also implements my `delegate` protocol. When I initalized my customView in the `Viewcontroller`, I add this `Viewcontroller` as the `delegate` by doing

```
var manualScreen = ManualScreen()
manualScreen.addListener(manualViewListener: self)
```

My delegate protocol is

```
protocol ManualViewListener {
    func addCount()
}
```

Once listener is set, I should be able to send some event (here button touch) from my view to the `ViewController` using `manualViewListener.addcount()`. But it says my `manualViewListener` is nil always.

*I have just written a small portion of my code here as writing everything will be not feasible. If anyone wants to see the whole app, here is the `GitHub` link to the thing I am working. https://github.com/Rikenm/Auto-Counter-iOS*

It doesn't look pretty for now. I am just working on the functionality right now.

**And finally thank you for the help.**

Comment: Are you seeing "adding listener" printing in your console?

Comment: ya and also I see "listener is nil" when I click the button. So confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {    
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)   

    xibSetup()  // this is the problem maker 
}
```

you add a new view of the same class above it and for sure it's listener object is nil with the the screen view that you instantiate here

```
mManualScreen = ManualScreen()
mManualScreen.addListener(manualViewListener: self)
```

//

```
  extension UIView{

    func xibSetup() {
        let view = loadFromNib()
        addSubview(view)
        stretch(view: view)
    }

//    2. Loads the view from the nib in the bundle
    /// Method to init the view from a Nib.
    ///
    /// - Returns: Optional UIView initialized from the Nib of the same class name.
    func loadFromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
        let selfType = type(of: self)
        let bundle = Bundle(for: selfType)
        let nibName = String(describing: selfType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)

        guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? T else {
            fatalError("Error loading nib with name \(nibName) ")
        }

        return view
    }
  }
```

Instead you need

```
var mManualViewListener:ManualViewListener! 

static func loadFromNib() -> ManualScreen {

   let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ManualScreen", owner: self, options: nil)?.first  as! ManualScreen
    return view
}
```

with

```
mManualScreen = ManualScreen.loadFromNib()

mManualScreen.addListener(manualViewListener: self)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're creating 2 separate `ManualScreen` instances. Your method `xibSetup` creates and returns *another* `ManualScreen` instance and adds it as a subview of your first `ManualScreen`, which is attached to your detail view controller. If you set a breakpoint within `addManualScreen()` in your `DetailViewController` and inspect `mManualScreen`'s subviews, you'll see another one.

Hence, you're setting the `mManualViewListener` delegate property to a `ManualScreen`, but the extra `ManualScreen` (which you shouldn't be creating) added as a subview from `xibSetup()` is intercepting the action, and *that* view doesn't have an `mManualViewListener` attached to it.

You should fix your view instantiation to only create one instance of `ManualScreen` and you will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a couple of breakpoints to your code. It seems the way you're adding the view is a little (a lot?) off.

### Settings Breakpoints

First off, I added a breakpoint to your `addManualScreen` method in line 89:

`containerView.addSubview(mManualScreen)`

And another breakpoint in your `ManualScreen` itself, the function `addButton`, line 51:

`if(mManualViewListener != nil){`

### First Breakpoint Hit

OK, breakpoint one hit. What is mManualScreen at this point?

`po mManualScreen`

gives us amongst other things the object ID `Auto_Counter.ManualScreen: 0x7fcfebe018d0`

is the delegate set?

`po mManualScreen.mManualViewListener`

indeed it is: `some : <Auto_Counter.DetailViewController: 0x7fcfeb837fb0>`

### Second Breakpoint Hit

OK, second breakpoint hit when I tap the + button. Is the `mManualListener` still set?

`po mManualViewListener`

Nope, we get `nil`

Lets take a look at the object itself then

`po self`

gives us

`Auto_Counter.ManualScreen: 0x7fcfe8d4b300`

Hang on, that's not the same object ID!

### The Problem

Now take a look at `xibSetup`

```
func xibSetup() {
    let view = loadFromNib()
    addSubview(view)
    stretch(view: view)
}
```

Here is where your second/inner view is created! And this is the view that reacts to your `@IBAction`.

### Solution

You should rethink how you create your manual view, I can't really come up with the correct solution as it seems a bit convoluted at the moment, but you need to use either the nib creation method...or create it manually.

**Update** It seems others has found the correct solution. I hope my answer helps you in how to diagnose these kinds of problems another time at least then so you can reduce the frustration period from a day to maybe just half a day :)

Hope that helps.